# Perforce: How to find out client view contains given path

Tags: perforce

I have a clientspec with view lines defined using perforce wildcards.
For example,

```
//depot/*/xyz/... //myClient/*/xyz/...
//depot/abc... //myClient/abc...
//depot/jkl/*pqr... //myClient/jkl/*pqr...
```

Now, given a path string, I need to find out whether the view lines contain it or not.

In the above example, third view line contains **//depot/jkl/123pqr789/dfg.c**

I am writing java program for this. I looked into p4java API but it won't help as javadoc for ViewMap class says,

*This implementation of view maps does not (yet) include advanced Perforce functionality (such as translation or testing the map to see whether a path is mapped or not), but future versions will; the emphasis here is on setting up a common basis for P4Java view maps.*

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing a 'p4 where' command to the server, and let it tell you: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/where.html#1040665